# Where can I ask how to find the common source of these voice files?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

My question on *Web Applications*, [*How to find the common source of these voice files?*](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/172251/how-to-find-the-common-source-of-these-voice-files), was closed, and it was suggested that I ask here about where to ask the question.

In case the other version gets deleted, here, for reference, is the question I'm planning to ask:

> Please say if there's a better place to ask this question.
>
> On two website for making video animations, [Kreado](https://www.KreadoAI.com) and [HeyGen](https://www.HeyGen.com), there is a selection of "text-to-speech" voices. The user inputs a script in text and selects a voice, and the software generates the sound of that voice speaking the script. On both websites, the user has to be logged in to a free account in order to see the list of voices available: [Kreado](https://www.kreadoai.com/ai/dubbing), [HeyGen](https://app.heygen.com/voices). Kreado offers 31 voices, while HeyGen has 92. Each voice is identified by a unique name, such as Christopher and Elizabeth.
>
> With so many voices, it can be hard to tell the difference between one and another. However, there is one voice that is very different from all the others, but seems to be the same voice on both sites. It is the voice of a little girl, and both sites call her Ana. For those people here who don't have accounts on those sites, I've used the Windows Game Bar to save the samples each site provides of Ana's voice:
>
> - [Kreado Ana](https://imgur.com/rRxwymd)
> - [HeyGen Ana](https://imgur.com/TVvYSnC)
>
> It's possible that both websites set their parameters for generating the voice of a little girl so similarly that their voices come out sounding the same, and it's possible that both sites just happened to give their little-girl voices as well as 15 other voices the same names as the other site, but that seems highly unlikely. What is more likely is that both sites have obtained these voices from another source, or perhaps Kreado is licensing its smaller selection of voices from HeyGen.
>
> In either case, I'd like to know what the common source of these voices is. How can I find that out?

Where might I ask this?

Comment: Questions should be self-contained, so you should add a summary of the question you posted on Web Applications instead of "forcing" readers to navigate there to be able to learn what you asked.

Comment: The 1st quoted sentence, like other social & meta content, does not belong in a post on SO.

Answer (score 4):

I know very little about most of the 182 sites in the Stack Exchange network. From my idea of what a question should be, it doesn't look like a good fit as it looks like a question "out of curiosity". I think you should look at each site having the voices that interested you; usually, this kind of site has a page with information about the software licenses they use.

It might be helpful that you explain why you want to find the source of the voices you mentioned. On specific settings, you should even have to work on adding supporting details for your guessings.

One approach is asking for a software recommendation in [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com), i.e., about a sound analyzer that helps you confirm that both sites are using the source files.

Another approach is to look around [Sound Design](https://sound.stackexchange.com/). In this community, you might learn helpful stuff from people who work in disciplines related to audio file creation.